# datadog how to compare 2 metrics to eachother

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have 2 metrics that I'm writing to datadog. They will be out of sync for a period of 1 hour each day while they are updating, but otherwise they should always be in-sync.

What type of monitor would support this to say that if metric A and metric B are not equal for a period of time consistent, then to alert?